# How to pronounce "2000-01"?

Tags: pronunciation

I wonder how to pronounce something like "2000-01 season". I checked the entries on [pronouncekiwi.com](http://www.pronouncekiwi.com/searchen?message=2000%E2%80%9301) for British and American English, but came across too many variations.

For example:

> - two thousand and one
> - two thousand to one
> - two thousand zero one

Is there any reason to prefer one of them, or are they the same? Which one is more formal?

Note: "2000-01" implies the years 2000 and 2001.

Comment: It depends somewhat on whether it’s the first season in 2000 or whether it’s a season spanning the years 2000 and 2001.

Comment: @Lawrence I've updated the post to clarify it.

Comment: You pronounce it "The writer couldn't be bothered to add two characters to avoid confusion".

Comment: Seriously, you don't have to transliterate this exactly when reading it out loud; you could say "the years two thousand and two thousand one" and it would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Spencer It's a little bit long. In the middle of the phrase, I may forget what I was talking about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> Two thousand to 'oh' one season

It is referring to a range of a time period, from the year 2000 up to the year 2001. Another way of writing this would also be " the 2000/01 season", implying a pronunciation of:

> The two thousand 'oh' one season

Comment: It's good to know both 2000-01 and 2000/01.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to some other answers, *I* would say (and I'm only adding hyphens to make a syntactic point; I obviously don't "say" them):

> The two-thousand-to-two-thousand-and-one season.

There is no *rule* for how "2000-01 season" should be interpreted in speech. Different people will say it differently.